# Good Question on Probability. A game is being played between $A$ and $B...$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$A$ and $B$ play for a prize; $A$ is to throw a die first, and is to win if he throws $6$. If he fails $B$ is to throw, and to win if he throws $6$ or $5$. If he fails, A is to throw again and to win with $6$ or $5$ or $4$, and so on : Find the chance of each player.

I don't know how to approach this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

- What is the probability $A$ wins on his first throw? ($1/6$)
- On his second throw? ($\frac56 \frac46 \frac36$)
- On his third throw?

Notice these are disjoint events, so what is the overall probability that $A$ wins?

Comment: for first throw it's $\frac {1}{6}$

Comment: @UMD correct, how about later ones? see update

Comment: $\frac56 \frac46 \frac36 \frac26 \frac56$

Comment: am i right.....

Comment: Please reply...

Comment: @UMD yes, can you finish the problem?

Comment: +1 I like your HINT much better than doing all the work for the OP.

Comment: @Bram28 agree, that has been my approach for a number of years here, I usually try to make the OP do some work on his own...

Comment: Same here ... too bad the OP's often don't appreciate that as much ...

Comment: What is 'OP'. ?

Comment: @UMD *OP* is an abbreviation of **O**riginal **P**oster

Answer (score 2):

Take this step by step.

Probability of A winning first throw is what?

$\frac{1}{6}$, because there’s one out of 6 outcomes he wins.

Likewise, the probability of B winning second throw is:
$$\frac{5}{6}*\frac{2}{6}$$ because A has to NOT throw a 6, then B has to throw either a 5 or 6.

Hopefully you can continue this, for example, the next one would be:

$$\frac{5}{6}*\frac{4}{6}*\frac{3}{6}$$

Since A and B have to not roll winning numbers, then A has to roll a 4,5 or 6.

When you get all the probabilities, simply sum them together, and you will get the chances of A and B winning. As a check, it should sum to 1.

While I have not given you the numerical answer, you should be able to figure out the second half of the solution on your own.